# Accelerating Iterations- MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, performance

Consider 2 Vectors `A = [20000000 x 1]` and `B = [20000000 x 1 ]`

I would need to find the sum of all A corresponding to every unique element of B.

Although this looks really easy, this is taking forever in MATLAB.

Currently, I am using

```
u = unique(B);
length_u = length(u);
C = zeros(length_u,1);

for i = 1:length_u
   C(i,1) = sum(A(B==u(i)));
end
```

Is there anyway to make it run faster? I tried splitting the loop and running 2 `parfor` loops using the parallel computing toolbox(because I have only 2 cores). Still takes hours.

P.S: Yes, I should get a better computer.

Comment: what is the bottleneck? the `unique` or the loop?

Comment: could you post your A and B matrices? For example, `A=randi(100,[20000000,1]);` etc.

Comment: @Shai Its the loop. Running over so many iterations. Matlab gets confused, I think.

Comment: If I do a `profile` of your code it's the `unique` for me.

Comment: @bdecaf what did you use for `A` and `B`? if `A` has relatively small number of unique elements the loop is no longer the bottleneck, but if `A` is large with many unique elements than the `unique` becomes negligble

Comment: @Shai - ah yes it seems I did not account for the whole loop properly.

Comment: @Nishanth is there any particular reason why you do not "accept" any answer to any of your questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428655/1714410) first.
If you must, you can use a combination of [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
A = randi( 500, 1, 100000 );
B = randi( 500, 1, 100000 );

ub = unique( B );

[ignore idx] = histc( B, [ub-.5 ub(end)+.5] );
C = accumarray( idx', A' )';
```

see a toy comparison to the naive `for`-loop implementation on [ideone](http://ideone.com/VCbNI0).

#### How does it work?

We use the second outout of `histc` to map elements of `B` (and later `A`) to the bins defined by the elements of `ub` (the unique elements of `B`).
`accumarray` is then used to sum all entries of `A` accorind to the mapping defined by `idx`.
Note: I assume the unique elements of `B` are at least 0.5 apart.

Comment: @Shai The only thing which is not quite nice in your solution is the fact which you have written in your "Note". But really well done. I didn't think about `histc`. +1

Comment: @TheMinion the +.5 can be averted by looking at the smallest abs diff in `ub` - but I wanted to keep the code simple.

Comment: you can (and shoudl) use ~ instead of ignore

Comment: @AnderBiguri you are right. However, I am used to an old version of Matlab that does not support `~` :(... old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3):

If `B` contains only integers, you can do it easily in one line, using the fact that [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) adds elements with the same index:

```
C = nonzeros(sparse(B,1,A));
```

Comment: Nice solution for integers. I didn't know `sparse` did this.

Comment: @TheMinion Thanks! Yes, it's not a very well known feature of Matlab. It more or less turns `sparse` into an `accumarray` with the `issparse` option

Comment: @LuisMendo in that respect `accumarray` is an extension of `sparse`. Using `accumarray` with `histc` generalize to non-integers as well.

Answer (score 3):

Further simplification of code suggested by **Shai**:

```
A = randi( 500, 1, 100000 );
B = randi( 500, 1, 100000 );

[~,~,idb] = unique( B );

C = accumarray( idb', A' )';
```

The `"idb"` here gives a vector same as that of `"idx"` in code suggested by [**Shai**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425249/1714410).

Answer (score 1):

I modified the sum. Instead of having to check each element rather it fits the case (`B==u(i)`) or not, I sorted the array and stopped the moment the element changed. While starting the next sum from that element. That way I only had to loop over each element in A ones, instead of `length_u` times. Here is the code I used:

```
A= rand(100000,1);
B= round(rand(100000,1)*25000);
u = unique(B);
length_u = length(u);
C = zeros(length_u,1);
E = zeros(length_u,1);
tic;
for k = 1:length_u
   C(k,1) = sum(A(B==u(k)));
end
t_OP=toc;

tic
D= sortrows([A,B],2);
n=1;
for l=1:numel(u)
    m=n;
    while m<numel(B) && D(m+1,2)==u(l) 
        m=m+1;
    end
    E(l,1) = sum(D(n:m,1));
    n=m+1;
end
t_trial=toc;
display(t_OP)
display(t_trial)
```

I used your code as well. The elapsed time for your code was: `t_OP=10.9398` and for my modification: `t_trial=0.0962`. Hopefully this helps. I made sure the code worked by building `sum(E-C)` which was `0`. 
 
**EDIT: Speedtest**

 
I compared it to **@Shai**'s solution as well. THis resulted in

```
t_OP =

   10.8147
t_trial =

    0.0984
t_Shai =

    0.0154
```

**EDIT: Comment by @moarningsun**

 
 Instead of using the `while`-loop. You can use the second output of unique if you sort your array before building the sum.

```
tic
A = randi( 25000, 1, 100000 );
B = randi( 25000, 1, 100000 );
D= sortrows([A',B'],2);
[u, idx] = unique(D(:,2));
idx = [idx; numel(D(:,2))+1];
for l=1:numel(u)
    E(l,1) = sum(D(idx(l):idx(l+1)-1,1));
end
t_trial=toc;
```

Comment: how does your method compares to `histc` and `accumarray`?

Comment: @Shai I edited my post. My modification resulted in a factor 100 compared to OP yours resulted in an aditional factor 10. So about 1000 times faster than OP.

Comment: You could also sort `B` first and then get the "boundary" indices from `[i, idx] = unique(B_sorted)`. It saves you the `while` loop.

Comment: @moarningsun You are right. I tried it but it didn't really change anything regarding run time. I will post it as a second Edit for future reference.